# In $\Delta ABC, $ $K$ and $L$ are points on $BC$. $AL$ is the bisector of $\angle KAC$. $KL\times BC=BK\times CL$. Find $\angle BAL$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

In $\Delta ABC$, $K$ and $L$ are points on $BC$. $K$ is closer to $B$ than $L$. $AL$ is the bisector of  $\angle KAC$. $KL\times BC=BK\times CL$. Find $\angle BAL$.

I have tried using angle-bisector theorem on $\Delta AKC$ without any result. I feel the angle is a right angle and have even tried to apply converse of Pythagoras' theorem on $\Delta ABL$. I tried applying Stewart's theorem on $\Delta ABL$ but I couldn't get the form of Pythagoras' theorem.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

By the bisector theorem we have

$$ \frac{AC}{AK}=\frac{CL}{KL}=\frac{BC}{BK} $$
hence
$$\mu= \frac{AC}{CB}=\frac{AK}{KB} $$
and $K$ belongs to the [Apollonius circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusCircle.html) that is the locus of points $P$ such that $\frac{PA}{PB}=\lambda$.
Such a circle goes through the feet of the angle bisectors (the internal and the external) from $C$.
If $ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle, such a circle intersects the $BC$ segment only at $C$, hence there is no solution.

[image]

On the other hand, if we allow $\widehat{BAC}$ to be greater than $90^\circ$, we have a solution at $\widehat{BAL}=\color{red}{90^\circ}$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The identity $KL \cdot BC = BK \cdot CL$ implies that line $AB$ is the external bisector of triangle $CKA$ at $A$ while $AL$ is the interior bisector at $A$. Hence they are orthogonal and thus the angle $\angle \, BAL = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: This implies that  $\angle \, BAC > 90^{\circ}$, contrary to the supposition that $\Delta ABC$ is acute-angled.

Comment: @JohnBentin He probably misunderstood the problem.